# Exchange 2013 CAS server unknown app pool name for services

Tags: windows, iis, exchange, cas

I have an problem with a CAS server that I'm trying to wrap my head around. This server was recently rebuilt (clean uninstall of Exchange 2013 and fresh install without restoring settings) in an attempt to address a similar issue and it came back.

This server is one of a few CAS servers working fine so I'm focused on something with this machine and less on the environment itself.

I first noticed the issue when the healthchecks (`https://servername/service/heatlhcheck.htm`) started failing. By failing, the servers did not return a response for the affected services

Some but not all services are affected. EWS/RPC is but OWA is not. All of them return very similar values as seen below:

Here is a wget of an affected server/service:

`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.`

```
Get-ServerHealth servername | Where-Object {$_.AlertValue -eq "Unhealthy"} | Format-List

    Server                  : servername
    CurrentHealthSetState   : NotApplicable
    Name                    : MaintenanceFailureMonitor.ECP
    TargetResource          : 
    HealthSetName           : ECP
    HealthGroupName         : CustomerTouchPoints
    AlertValue              : Unhealthy
    FirstAlertObservedTime  : 3/9/2014 3:20:55 PM
    Description             : 
    IsHaImpacting           : False
    RecurranceInterval      : 300
    DefinitionCreatedTime   : 3/9/2014 3:03:03 PM
    HealthSetDescription    : 
    ServerComponentName     : None
    LastTransitionTime      : 3/9/2014 3:20:55 PM
    LastExecutionTime       : 3/10/2014 9:36:29 PM
    LastExecutionResult     : Succeeded
    ResultId                : 236535
    WorkItemId              : 36
    IsStale                 : False
    Error                   : 
    Exception               : 
    IsNotified              : False
    LastFailedProbeId       : -1457016208
    LastFailedProbeResultId : 6251
    ServicePriority         : 0
    Identity                : ECP\MaintenanceFailureMonitor.ECP\
    IsValid                 : True
    ObjectState             : New
```

Further troubleshooting, I ran this:

```
Invoke-MonitoringProbe EWS.Proxy\EWSProxyTestProbe -Server servername | Format-List

    RunspaceId         : 75f59bdc-73d0-41f4-8e67-a9f3dc2eb316
    Server             : servername
    MonitorIdentity    : EWS.Proxy\EWSProxyTestProbe
    RequestId          : d4aba43d-b521-4afc-af90-001192b603be
    ExecutionStartTime : 3/11/2014 1:48:06 AM
    ExecutionEndTime   : 3/11/2014 1:48:06 AM
    Error              : Unknown app pool name: 
    Exception          : System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown app pool name: 
                    at    Microsoft.Exchange.Monitoring.ActiveMonitoring.ClientAccess.CafeLocalProbe.DoWork(Cancellati
                 onToken cancellationToken)
                    at Microsoft.Office.Datacenter.WorkerTaskFramework.WorkItem.Execute(CancellationToken 
                 joinedToken)
                    at 
                 Microsoft.Office.Datacenter.WorkerTaskFramework.WorkItem.<>c__DisplayClass2.<StartExecuting>b__0()
                    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    PoisonedCount      : 0
    ExecutionId        : 47266517
    SampleValue        : 0
    ExecutionContext   : Probe Absolute Timeout=60000ms, Timeout Value=60000ms, Calculated HttpRequest Timeout=59000ms                 
    FailureContext     : 
    ExtensionXml       : 
    ResultType         : Failed
    RetryCount         : 0
    ResultName         : d4aba43db5214afcaf90001192b603be-EWSProxyTestProbe
    IsNotified         : False
    ResultId           : 49856
    ServiceName        : InvokeNow
    StateAttribute1    : 
    StateAttribute2    : 
    StateAttribute3    : 
    StateAttribute4    : 
    StateAttribute5    : 
    StateAttribute6    : 0
    StateAttribute7    : 0
    StateAttribute8    : 0
    StateAttribute9    : 0
    StateAttribute10   : 0
    StateAttribute11   : 
    StateAttribute12   : 
    StateAttribute13   : 
    StateAttribute14   : 
    StateAttribute15   : 
    StateAttribute16   : 0
    StateAttribute17   : 0
    StateAttribute18   : 0
    StateAttribute19   : 0
    StateAttribute20   : 0
    StateAttribute21   : 
    StateAttribute22   : 
    StateAttribute23   : 
    StateAttribute24   : 
    StateAttribute25   : 
    Identity           : e8f7991f8b0141bfa85c9e2b8b66b1a2
    IsValid            : True
    ObjectState        : New
```

I've tried recycling the app engine and rebooting. Still no luck. Any ideas?